# Magento setup directory cannot be accessed

Tags: error, installation, permissions, setup, apache

I am trying to setup Magento on a Apache MacOS local system. I have uploaded the Magento Community Edition 2.0.12 from the official [download source](https://magento.com/tech-resources/download), unzipped them in my `~/myusername/Sites/magento` directory. But when I am visit the `http://localhost/~myusername/magento/` url I get the following screen:

[image]

When I then check the `magento/var/report/661788277795` file it returns me the following errors:

```
NOTE: You cannot install Magento using the Setup Wizard because the Magento setup directory cannot be accessed.
You can install Magento using either the command line or you must restore access to the following directory: /Users/myusername/Sites/magento/setup
```

The file permissions of the setup file are:

```
drwxr-xr-x@  9 _www  staff     306 14 feb 16:47 setup
```

I don't know why magento tells me to restore the access to the setup directory, while the _www user can read, write and execute.

Answer (score 7):

Appending /setup to the install URL should resolve the issue. In your case that would be http://localhost/~myusername/magento/setup